# R Regex / gsub : How to collapse spaces in a string

Tags: regex, perl, r, gsub

I have a vector of sentences that were scanned from handwritten documents.  In the process there were some spacing problems like this:

```
 The d og is br own.
```

I was curious if there was a way to generically take any pattern with `'_x_'` or space-character-space and collapse the second space like this:

```
The d og is br own.  --> The dog is br own.
```

I'm only worried about a single character between the spaces  (`'_x_'` NOT `'_xx_'`).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know how you can determine that "The d og" should be "The dog" or "Thed og" without a corpus.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Agreed, I'm trying to see if there's a way to uniformly collapse either the first or 2nd space on all of them, then let spellchecker have a look at it and see how it turns out.

Comment: Oh, duh... missed that part.  Guess it's time for some sleep.

Comment: Haha, no worries, thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

```
> x<-"The d og is br own."
> gsub(" (.) "," \\1",x)
[1] "The dog is br own."
```

or

```
gsub(" ([[:alnum:]]) "," \\1",x)
```

`(.)` matches anything `([[:alnum:]])` matches alphanumeric characters only.